# use correctly notificationCenter addObserverForName with blocks

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

How can I, in clean way, instantiate 2 BOOL variables in a block ?

As follow, it's working but I have "Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle", which obviously is not good...

```
    [notificationCenter addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                    object:nil
                                     queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                         isApplicationOnForegroundMode = NO;
                                         isApplicationOnBackgroundMode = YES;
                                     } ];


    [notificationCenter addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                    object:nil
                                     queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                         isApplicationOnForegroundMode = YES;
                                         isApplicationOnBackgroundMode = NO;
                                     } ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that `isApplicationOnForegroundMode` and `isApplicationOnBackgroundMode` are ivars.

You'll need to add a couple of ivars or properties to track the observation blocks so you can remove them.  I'll call those `id` properties backgroundObserver and activeObserver.

Update your code to:

```
__unsafe_unretained <<self's class>> *this = self; // or __weak, on iOS 5+.

self.backgroundObserver = [notificationCenter 
                             addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                         object:nil
                                          queue:mainQueue 
                                     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                         this->isApplicationOnForegroundMode = NO;
                                         // or: this.isApplicationOnForegroundMode = YES, if you have a property declared
                                         this->isApplicationOnBackgroundMode = YES;
                                     } ];


self.activeObserver = [notificationCenter 
                         addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                     object:nil
                                      queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                          this->isApplicationOnForegroundMode = YES;
                                          this->isApplicationOnBackgroundMode = NO;
                                      } ];
```

You will also need to make sure that you call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.backgroundObserver];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.activeObserver];
```

in `-dealloc`.

Comment: I think the new block based notification observers return an id object that should be use for removing the observer.  I don't know if they are the same as self.  Are they?

Comment: No. The `object` parameter is a mechanism for filtering notification delivery, typically to say "I only want notification X when it's sent by object Y".  You can remove an observer by matching just the observer, the observer and the notification name, or the observer and the notification name and the observed object, but in dealloc the form above is simplest and most effective: it says "remove me from all notifications".

Comment: I dont' think I was clear with my question.  For the addObserverForName:... method call, there is no where where you put "who" is doing the observing.  The method returns an id that should be  used for removing the observer.  The observer is not self. Read the document for addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock under discussion.

Comment: @John Ah, yes: you are absolutely correct.  I haven't used the block-based notification methods before.  I'll update my code to reflect it.